# How to access django model instance from class applied with contribute_to_class

Tags: django, django-models

I'm adding tracker class  to Model using `contribute_to_class`.

F.e.

```
class Tracker(object):
    watched_class = None

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name=None):
         self.watched_class = cls

class Post(models.model):
    ...
    tracker = Tracker()
```

So I can access tracker via `Post.tracker`. But in some operations it'll be good to have access to model instance so instead of using `Post.tracker.do_some_stuff(post_instance)` I could use `post_instance.do_some_stuff()`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
class Tracker(object):

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name=None):

        def do_some_stuff(instance):
            print instance

        cls.do_some_stuff = do_some_stuff
```

Comment: I don't want to modify original class.

Comment: Hm, according to it's name `contribute_to_class` method modifies the original class :-) For example it is the same mechanism which introduces `get_FIELD_display` methods for `CharField` with `choices` attribute.

Comment: I mean it's more patently to use `post.tracker.get_changes() instead of post.get_tracker_changes()` :)

Comment: But I realized that I'll have to generate new Tracker instance for the each Post object, so I guess adding a new method to the tracked class it's the only option I have